# Unable to disable a button which has IsEnabled bound to a property

Tags: c#, maui

I have a problem where I can't seem to disable a button which has IsEnabled bound to a property.

I have the following XAML:

```
 <Button Text="Skip" IsEnabled="{Binding SkipEnabled}" ...  />
```

It is being bound to this BindableProperty:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty SkipEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(SkipEnabled), returnType: typeof(bool?), declaringType: typeof(WizardMasterPage), propertyChanged: SetSkipEnabled, 
        defaultValue: null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public bool? SkipEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool?)GetValue(SkipEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SkipEnabledProperty, value); }
    }
```

The problem is the button is always enabled.

The propertyChanged event isn't firing on the pages where the property is set to false - presumably because it is false when the page is created, so doesn't think it has changed and hence the binding is not updated. I notice that it does fire on the pages where I set the property to True.

Has anyone else seen this? Are there any workarounds?

Note: I tried just bool as well and that didn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like the property change event is not being fired when you set the SkipEnabled property to false. One potential workaround for this is to explicitly call OnPropertyChanged method in the SkipEnabled property setter whenever the value is changed. This should notify the UI that the property value has changed and the binding should update accordingly

Comment: IsEnabled only has TWO states (true/false). Maybe it doesn't correctly understand `bool?` which has THREE states. Change BindableProperty and its associated Property to `bool`. Work any better? BUT you are correct: property changed is ONLY called when it changes; SetSkipEnabled won't be called until there is a change. You might need to call it yourself in constructor, to apply default state.

Comment: Actually it turns out that it's not a binding problem. Even if I make it IsEnabled=False I have the same problem. I have no other code which would do this so I am guessing there is a maui bug somewhere here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this `Button` included in a `ContentView`, right?

If yes, then  you can refer to the following code.
I achieved this function  and I added a Button on the current page to reset the value, then the UI could refresh automatically.

**ChildView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ChildView : ContentView 
{
    public String YourName
    {
        get
        {
            String value = (String)GetValue(YourNameProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YourNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YourName)
    , typeof(String)
    , typeof(ChildView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

   
    public bool SkipEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            bool value = (bool)GetValue(SkipEnabledProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SkipEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SkipEnabled)
    , typeof(bool)
    , typeof(ChildView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

    static void OnYourNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------> " + newValue);
    }

    
    public ChildView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**ChildView.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.ChildView"
             x:Name="TestControlView"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=YourName}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button Text="Skip" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=SkipEnabled}"  />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mauiapp="clr-namespace:MauiContentViewApp"
             
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <mauiapp:MyViewModel></mauiapp:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

     <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <mauiapp:ChildView YourName="{Binding TestName}"  SkipEnabled="{Binding TestBoolvalue}" ></mauiapp:ChildView>

            <Button Text="reset"  Command="{Binding ResetValueCommand}"/>
     </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
  
    private string _testName;
    public string TestName
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _testName, value); }
        get { return _testName; }
    }

    private bool _testBoolValue;
    public bool TestBoolvalue
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _testBoolValue, value); }
        get { return _testBoolValue; }
    }


    public ICommand ResetValueCommand => new Command(resetMethod);

    private void resetMethod(object obj)
    {
        TestName = "reset test string";

        TestBoolvalue = !TestBoolvalue;
    }


    public MyViewModel()
    {
        TestName = "test string";

        TestBoolvalue = false;
    }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jessie Zhang -MSFT thanks for the suggestion. In fact your suggestion triggered a thought which solved my problem. It turns out the issue is to do with the fact that I hadn't been using CanExecute on the RelayCommand. It seems even if you don't have CanExecute the IsEnabled property is useless. So I had to move away from using IsEnabled, which is a shame because I now need to implement the method on pages where it isn't even needed.